# Is it a Google Places request if I just add the api key?

Tags: ios, swift, google-places-api

If in AppDelegate I just do the following, is it consider a request if I do nothing else with it?

```
GMSPlacesClient.provideAPIKey("API-KEY-HERE")
```

Thanks

Comment: No, that's just configuring the client.

Comment: @rmaddy, Ok great thanks.